# mdaemon wont display body in webmail

Tags: webmail

When you login to my Mdaemon webmail through a browser you can see a list of emails, but when you click on a email you don't see the body, it's blank. You also can send e-mail but you can't receive it. How can I trouble shoot this problem, or what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that MDaemon was somehow corrupted. I tried to just do a repair, but it didn't work. I backed up all the mail boxes and then uninstalled it, and then reinstalled it, and that fixed all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue of not seeing the email in your browser, does this happen on all browsers? Do you have any third-party antivirus software on the machine? Does the issue persist if you temporarily disable it for troubleshooting purposes? What version of MDaemon are you running?

For the issue of not being able to receive emails, if you have someone send you a test message, examine your MDaemon-SMTP(in).log file. Do you see the connection coming in? If not, then I'd start with your firewall configuration.

If you need more in-depth troubleshooting, I'd recommend opening a ticket with the Alt-N Support team via this link:

http://www.altn.com/Support/RequestSupport/